# change css bootstrap menu active link color

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Hello I have issues regarding css bootstrap menu I cant change active link color which means that after I click on link and move mouse pointer out of the area the link background turns to white but I need it transparent how can I change that ?

I tried these methods:

```
navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
  background-color:red;
}

.nav li:active {
  background-color:transparent !important ;
}
```

and many more....

Comment: which version of bootstrap?

Comment: try `:focus`...

Comment: bootstrap 3.3.7

Comment: try `.nav li.active {`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
.nav>li>a:hover,
.nav>li>a:focus {
  background-color: transparent !important; //or whatever you want 
}
```